# Google Analytics... pretty easy question about tracking subdomains

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

This is barely even a question, I'd just like someone to confirm this for me! :)

Google Analytics has generated my tracking code for the subdomain sub.mysite.com. A line of the tracking code looks like this:

`_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.mysite.com']);`

Do I need to change `.mysite.com` to `sub.mysite.com`? The tracking code page auto generates instructions for cases like these, but it mentions nothing about actually configuring it. I mean, does it detect the subdomain automatically, or am I being thick?

Cheers!

Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.mysite.com']);` (note the `.` before `mysite.com`) causes the tracking to take place on all subdomains of `mysite.com`. See [the documentation for `_setDomainName` in the Google Analytics Tracker API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiDomainDirectory.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setDomainName).

If you only want to enable tracking for `sub.mysite.com`, you can just use this instead:

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'sub.mysite.com']);
```

P.S. You might also be interested in my post on [optimizing the asynchronous Google Analytics snippet in terms of byte size *and* performance](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-analytics-snippet).